# MySQL Query causing high CPU and taking forever to execute

Tags: mysql, innodb, index-tuning

this below query takes a long time to execute in excess of 120 seconds, upon checking the explain plan it seems to be using **using where, using temporary; using filesort**. Since the application is a third party I do

```
SELECT ii.*, 
count(iic.postDate) as itemCommentCount, 
count(iif.postDate) as itemFileCount,
iis.statusDate as itemStatus_statusDate, 
iis.statusKey as itemStatus_statusKey, 
pp.name as project_name, 
mm.title as member_title, 
mm.firstName as member_firstName, 
mm.middleName as member_middleName, 
mm.lastName as member_lastName, 
mm.username as member_username, 
mp.position 
FROM 
    frk_item as ii INNER JOIN frk_itemStatus AS iis ON ii.itemId = iis.itemId 
    LEFT JOIN frk_project AS pp ON ii.projectId = pp.projectId 
    LEFT JOIN frk_memberProject AS mp ON ii.projectId = mp.projectId AND mp.memberId=5                 LEFT JOIN frk_member AS mm ON ii.memberId = mm.memberId 
    LEFT JOIN frk_itemComment AS iic ON ii.itemId=iic.itemId 
    LEFT JOIN frk_itemFile AS iif ON ii.itemId=iif.itemId  
WHERE 
    ii.projectId = '2' AND (showPrivate=0 OR showPrivate=1 OR (showPrivate=2 AND (ii.memberId=5 OR ii.authorId=5)))
     AND ((deadlineDate < '2015-09-15' OR statusKey = 3)) 
     AND iis.statusDate=(
        SELECT MAX(iis2.statusDate) 
            FROM frk_itemStatus AS iis2 
            WHERE 
                ii.itemId = iis2.itemId
         ) 
     AND iis.statusDate=(
        SELECT  MAX(iis2.statusDate) 
            FROM frk_itemStatus AS iis2 
                WHERE ii.itemId = iis2.itemId
            ) 
GROUP BY ii.itemId , ii.itemId ORDER BY deadlineDate ASC, deadlineDate ASC, priority
```

I feel the query is poorly designed however as its a part of 3rd party software, dont have much control of what can be done. Is there something on the index front I can do to speed it up?

the indexes on the frk_item look like

```
 SHOW INDEX FROM frk_item;

| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| frk_item |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            1 | itemId         | A         |       37237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | projectId                  |            1 | projectId      | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | memberId                   |            1 | memberId       | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | missing_authoriid          |            1 | authorId       | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | missing_showprivate        |            1 | showPrivate    | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | frk_item_fulltext          |            1 | title          | NULL      |       37237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | frk_item_fulltext          |            2 | description    | NULL      |       37237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| frk_item |          1 | frk_item_fulltext          |            3 | cannedQuestion | NULL      |       37237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |          |
+----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

and

```
##EXPLAIN PLAN for the query ##

| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                    | key       | key_len | ref                                | rows  | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | PRIMARY            | ii    | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,projectId,memberId,missing_authoriid,missing_showprivate,frk_item_fulltext               | projectId | 3       | const                              | 18618 |   50.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
| 1 | PRIMARY            | pp    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pranav_project                                                                           | PRIMARY   | 3       | library_support.ii.projectId       |    1   100.00 | NULL                                               |
| 1 | PRIMARY            | mp    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                          | PRIMARY   | 6       | const,library_support.ii.projectId |    1 |  100.00 | NULL                                               |
| 1 | PRIMARY            | mm    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                          | PRIMARY   | 3       | library_support.ii.memberId        |    1 |  100.00 | NULL                                               |
| 1 | PRIMARY            | iic   | NULL       | ref    | taskId                                                                                           | taskId    | 4       | library_support.ii.itemId          |    1 |  100.00 | NULL                                               |
| 1 | PRIMARY            | iif   | NULL       | ALL    | taskId                                                                                           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                               |    1 |  100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 1 | PRIMARY            | iis   | NULL       | ref    | itemId                                                                                           | itemId    | 4       | library_support.ii.itemId          |    3 |  100.00 | Using where                                        |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | iis2  | NULL       | ref    | itemId                                                                                           | itemId    | 4       | library_support.ii.itemId          |    3 |  100.00 | NULL                                               |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | iis2  | NULL       | ref    | itemId                                                                                           | itemId    | 4       | library_support.ii.itemId          |    3 |  100.00 | NULL                                               |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL engine being used is InnoDB and version is 5.7.8rc

Comment: Is there no way to rewrite the query? Removing the `dependent subquery` part would be a good start. Splitting it into multiple queries with one query per one basic OR might help too. If really not possible then you might try using [covering indexes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) (good read in any case)

Comment: covering index didn't helped much. Is there anything else which I should try?

Comment: Can you add the new explain with those new indexes?

Answer (score 3):

The two dependent subqueries seem to be identical??  Remove one.

`GROUP BY ii.itemId , ii.itemId`  Eh??  Remove one of them.  `deadlineDate ASC, deadlineDate ASC` Ditto.

Index on frk_itemStatus:  `INDEX(itemId, statusDate)`

> AND ((deadlineDate < '2015-09-15' OR statusKey = 3))

`OR` can be deadly on performance.  Consider using `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... AND deadlineDate < '2015-09-15' ... )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... AND statusKey = 3 ... )
```

together with

```
INDEX(projectId, deadlineDate)
INDEX(projectId, statusKey)
```

Ah.  Perhaps the best idea came when I noticed  `GROUP BY ii.item_id`.  Grouping by a unique key is a symptom of exploding number of rows due to JOINs, then reigning them back in by using that grouping.  So, instead,...

First, formulate this to get *just* the ids of the interesting rows.

```
( SELECT itemId FROM frk_item ... )
```

Then, do the `JOINs` to get the rest of the data:

```
SELECT lots-of-stuff
    FROM ( SELECT itemId FROM frk_item ... ) AS ids
    JOIN frk_item AS f  ON f.itemId = ids.itemId  -- to get other frk_item fields
    JOIN the-rest-of-the-joins
    WHERE ...   -- if not already moved into the subquery
    # GROUP BY  -- remove!
    ORDER BY ...
```

This speeds things up by (1) avoiding the explode-implode and (2) avoiding the tmp table for the `GROUP BY`.